# microsoft office interop excel open file without saving

Tags: c#, excel

I use this code to create excel worksheet:

```
 Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
 Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
 Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add();
 excelWorkSheet.Name = fileName;

 ... fill worksheet
```

Is there a way to open this worksheet (show it on screen)
without saving it?

Answer (score 6):

Sure, just show your Excel instance:

```
excelApp.Visible = true;
```