# Temporary excel file with Interop library

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm creating excel from datatable using Interop Library so my method is simple as:

```
public bool WriteDataTableToExcel(System.Data.DataTable dataTable, string worksheetName, string saveAsLocation, string ReporType)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelworkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelCellrange;

    try
    {
        // Start Excel and get Application object.
        excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        // for making Excel visible
        excel.Visible = false;
        excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

        // Creation a new Workbook
        excelworkBook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

        // Workk sheet
        excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelworkBook.ActiveSheet;
        excelSheet.Name = worksheetName;


        excelSheet.Cells[1, 1] = ReporType;
        excelSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

        // loop through each row and add values to our sheet
        int rowcount = 2;

        foreach (DataRow datarow in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            rowcount += 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                // on the first iteration we add the column headers
                if (rowcount == 3)
                {
                    excelSheet.Cells[2, i] = dataTable.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                    excelSheet.Cells.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

                }

                excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, i] = datarow[i - 1].ToString();

                //for alternate rows
                if (rowcount > 3)
                {
                    if (i == dataTable.Columns.Count)
                    {
                        if (rowcount % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            excelCellrange = excelSheet.Range[excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, 1], excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, dataTable.Columns.Count]];
                            FormattingExcelCells(excelCellrange, "#CCCCFF", System.Drawing.Color.Black, false);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }

        // now we resize the columns
        excelCellrange = excelSheet.Range[excelSheet.Cells[1, 1], excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, dataTable.Columns.Count]];
        excelCellrange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Borders border = excelCellrange.Borders;
        border.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        border.Weight = 2d;


        excelCellrange = excelSheet.Range[excelSheet.Cells[1, 1], excelSheet.Cells[2, dataTable.Columns.Count]];
        FormattingExcelCells(excelCellrange, "#000099", System.Drawing.Color.White, true);


        //now save the workbook and exit Excel


        excelworkBook.SaveAs(saveAsLocation); ;
        excelworkBook.Close();
        excel.Quit();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        excelSheet = null;
        excelCellrange = null;
        excelworkBook = null;
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// FUNCTION FOR FORMATTING EXCEL CELLS
/// </summary>
/// <param name="range"></param>
/// <param name="HTMLcolorCode"></param>
/// <param name="fontColor"></param>
/// <param name="IsFontbool"></param>
public void FormattingExcelCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range, string HTMLcolorCode, System.Drawing.Color fontColor, bool IsFontbool)
{
    range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(HTMLcolorCode);
    range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(fontColor);
    if (IsFontbool == true)
    {
        range.Font.Bold = IsFontbool;
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm saving excel to path with this code:

```
excelworkBook.SaveAs(saveAsLocation);
```

After call this method I use  `Process.Start(fileName);` to open excel file.It works prefectly, But that I want to achieve is to open this excel without saving it to a path I just want to open, like temporary file. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Excel requires a file.  Consider Path.GetTempFileName() unless you do this at a high rate.

Comment: @HansPassant , wouldn't `.Visible = true;` just show the current excel instance? i.e: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31310820/microsoft-office-interop-excel-open-file-without-saving

Comment: All I dislike about it is that I didn't think of it :)  Getting the window into the foreground might be a bit awkward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saving the file instead of showing your Excel instance:

```
    ...
    //now save the workbook and exit Excel

    //excelworkBook.SaveAs(saveAsLocation); ;
    //excelworkBook.Close();
    //excel.Quit();

    excel.Visible = true;
    return true;
}
```

You first set `excel.Visible = false;`, this will keep excel as a background process. Instead, at the end of the scope, add `excel.Visible = true;` after all the computing is complete. I commented out the lines that wouldn't be necessary just so you can see where I would put the new line.

Comment: @Jonathan , no problem. Feel free to mark as answer when able (to close the question) and happy coding!